Can I use IAM to verify a request is from my AWS account?
I have a server running on a datacenter. It is a self managed server which includes a restapi server running on it. I have a lambda in AWS that needs to call the restapi. I am thinking to setup a security check on the server to check if the request is from my AWS account or not. Is it something IAM supported?
What I am thinking is to create an IAM user and load the key and the credential on the server. The lambda will put a signature on the request header. When the server receives the request, it can use its IAM role to verify if the request is from the specific account. Is it something achievable?

The signature is simply a hash of a shared secret. There is no need to specifically use an IAM credentials as the secret. You could just make your own random shared secret and then use it to 'sign' the request to your server. Your server would verify the hash by creating a hash using the same process.
